# get mouse positions in stroke canvas

Tags: javascript, qt, canvas, qml, mouseevent

I have created a custom arc progress with canvas in qml. I have drawn the progress in canvas according to the time elapsed. Now i need to seek through the progress bar, like the music seek bar, how can we get the correct x,y position in the stroke in canvas.

This is the code to draw arc

```
import QtQml 2.2
import QtQuick 2.0

// draws two arcs (portion of a circle)
// fills the circle with a lighter secondary color
// when pressed
Canvas {
    id: canvas
    width: canvasWidth
    height: canvasHeight
    antialiasing: true

    property color primaryColor: "grey"
    property color secondaryColor: "white"

    property int canvasWidth: 0
    property int canvasHeight: 0

    property real centerWidth: width / 2
    property real centerHeight: height / 2
    property real radius: Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2 - 2

    property real minimumValue: 0
    property real maximumValue: 100
    property real currentValue: 33

    // this is the angle that splits the circle in two arcs
    // first arc is drawn from 0 radians to angle radians
    // second arc is angle radians to 2*PI radians
    property real angle: ((currentValue - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue) * 2 * Math.PI)

    // we want both circle to start / end at 12 o'clock
    // without this offset we would start / end at 9 o'clock
    property real angleOffset: (-Math.PI / 2)

    property string text: "Text"

    signal clicked()

    onPrimaryColorChanged: requestPaint()
    onSecondaryColorChanged: requestPaint()
    onMinimumValueChanged: requestPaint()
    onMaximumValueChanged: requestPaint()
    onCurrentValueChanged: requestPaint()

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.save();

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // First, thinner arc
        // From angle to 2*PI

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeStyle = primaryColor;
        ctx.arc(canvas.centerWidth,
                canvas.centerHeight,
                canvas.radius,
                angleOffset + canvas.angle ,
                (angleOffset-0.1) + 2*Math.PI );
        ctx.stroke();


        // Second, thicker arc
        // From 0 to angle

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeStyle = canvas.secondaryColor;
        ctx.arc(canvas.centerWidth,
                canvas.centerHeight,
                canvas.radius,
                canvas.angleOffset,
                canvas.angleOffset + canvas.angle);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();



    }



    function xOnArc(radius, radianAngle) {
           var x = canvas.centerWidth + radius * Math.cos(radianAngle);
           return   x-(rect.width/2)
       }
    function yOnArc(radius, radianAngle) {
           var y = canvas.centerHeight + radius * Math.sin(radianAngle);
           return y-rect.height/2
       }



    Rectangle
   {
       id: rect
       color: "white"
       height: 10
       width: 10
       radius: 10/2
       x: xOnArc(canvas.radius,canvas.angleOffset + canvas.angle)
       y: yOnArc(canvas.radius,canvas.angleOffset + canvas.angle)


//       Behavior on x
//       {
//           NumberAnimation {properties: "x"; duration:10}
//       }

//       Behavior on y
//       {
//           NumberAnimation {properties: "y"; duration:10}
//       }

   }
}
```

This is the code where i would show progress according to the time elapsed

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    property real value: 0
    height: canvasHeights
    width: canvasWidths
    property real total_time: 180
    property real progress_time: 0
    property bool isPlaying: song_timer.running
    signal songCompleted()
    property int canvasWidths: 240
    property int canvasHeights: 240

    property int text_margin_progress: 0

    /**
      A custom control which draws the the progress Arc in canvas
      */
    ProgressArc
    {
        id: circle
        currentValue: value
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        canvasWidth: canvasWidths
        canvasHeight: canvasHeights


        /**
          A timer will be started when the song starts playing this controls the progress of the song
          */
        Timer
        {
            id: song_timer
            running: false
            repeat: true
            interval: 1000
            onTriggered:
            {
                //progress_time will be incremented after each second which will be used to calculate the progress percentage and
                //and time
                progress_time = progress_time + 1;
                value = calculateStepValue(progress_time)
                circle.currentValue = value;
                time.text = fmtMSS(progress_time)

                /**
                  When value reaches 100 then the song is completed and a signal will be send to the corresponsing class
                  */
                if(value >=100)
                {
                    song_timer.stop()
                    songCompleted()

                }
            }
        }


        /**
          Elapsed time will be shown in the text
          */
        Text
        {
            id: time
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: text_margin_progress
            color: "white"
            font.pointSize: (canvasHeights == (350*scaleFactor-(20*scaleFactor)))?20:10
        }

    }

    /**
      Convert seconds to human readable format
      eg:- 68 sec eq 1:08 min
      */
    function fmtMSS(time){
        // Hours, minutes and seconds
        var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
        var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        // Output like "1:01" or "4:03:59" or "123:03:59"
        var ret = "";
        if (hrs > 0) {
            ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
        }
        ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
        ret += "" + secs;
        return ret;
    }


    /**
      Calculate the step value from the progress time
      */
    function calculateStepValue(current_time)
    {
        return (100 - (((total_time - current_time)/total_time)*100))
    }


    /**
      pause playing music
      */
    function pausePlaying()
    {
        song_timer.stop();
    }

    /**
      Resume playing music
      */
    function resumePlaying()
    {
        if(value>100)
            songCompleted()
        else
            song_timer.start()
    }

    /**
      Start playing song. Before playing set the progress time to 0{song from start}
      */
    function startPlaying()
    {
        progress_time = 0
        song_timer.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `MouseArea` to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you need add [`MouseArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) into your `Item` or directly to `ProgressArc` (from the second listing):

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Clicked on " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y)
        var percent = calcPercentBasedOnMousePos(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        jumpToPosition(percent)
    }
}
```

Do not forget to set anchors to fill parent item (otherwise this `MouseArea` will be `0x0` size and couldn't handle any clicks).

You can see dummy implementation of [`onClicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#clicked-signal) handler -- it is about how I see your task. So you can freely operate by [`x`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html#x-prop) and [`y`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html#y-prop) value on your own.